# Three.js STL loader with TypeScript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'XHRLoader' of undefined

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am trying to import an STL file to Three.js, but the `three-stl-loader` npm-module does not find the `THREE` object.

This code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import * as THREESTLLoader from 'three-stl-loader'

var STLLoader = new THREESTLLoader()
var loader = new STLLoader(THREE)
loader.load('path/to/file.stl', function (geometry: any) {})
```

Produces this error:
[image]

On line 45 in index.js (in the stl-loader), the `three-stl-loader` module makes use of the `THREE` object, but it seems like the module does not know about the `THREE` object at all:
[image]

The project is compiled with TypeScript in Webpack. I think there may be a problem with the way it is compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like i found the missing part.
As the module, and not the constructor, has to receive the `THREE` object, I only needed to add `THREE` to the module instead:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import * as THREESTLLoader from 'three-stl-loader'

var STLLoader = new THREESTLLoader(THREE) // Added THREE
var loader = new STLLoader() // Removed THREE
loader.load('path/to/file.stl', function (geometry: any) {})
```